# How to get solution for Nonlinear simultanious differential equations in easiest way?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Suppose, I have a system of simultaneous nonlinear differential equations as follows:

```
x'=x-x^3-x*y^2-a*x+h
y'=y-y^3-y*x^2+a*y
```

where, x & y are variable ; x' & y' represents time derivative of x and y ; a & h are parameters.

Now to solve this, one can use DSolve or by taking x'=0 & y'=0 (for fixed point calculation) , i.e. take the polynomial and by using FindRoot or Ruduce or other options.

My quarry is that what is the easiest way to get fixed points (solutions) in terms of a & h .

Comment: Could use `In[14]:= Solve[{x - x^3 - x*y^2 - a*x + h, y - y^3 - y*x^2 + a*y} == 
  0, {x, y}, Cubics -> False]` to get parametrized solutions, some using `Root` objects. They evaluate numerically when given values for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can obtain the fixed points with `Solve`:

```
Solve[{x - x^3 - x*y^2 - a*x + h == 0, y - y^3 - y*x^2 + a*y == 0}, {x, y}]
```

However, this will not work in general.

Comment: then for general purpose what command should I use @Henrik

Comment: `FindRoot`. But you can use a long-time solution from `NDSolve` as starting value.